# PhoneGap 2.1.0 and iOS Local Notifications

Tags: cordova, uilocalnotification

I have been trying to integrate [Drew Dahlman's plugin](https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Phonegap-LocalNotification) for iOS local notifications in my PhoneGap app.

Have been looking at the instructions [here](http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=84) and [here](http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=117), but haven't been able to get it to work yet. It seems like the instructions apply more to the older versions of PhoneGap and don't match with how the folders are PhoneGap 2.1.0.

Has anybody been able to get this plugin to work with the recent phone gap versions ?

Any other suggestions for iOS local notification plugins for PhoneGap are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the [working example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/LocalNotification) of the local notifications plugin, and tried to build that.

Had no luck, because the example was using Cordova 1.6.0.

Finally, I found PhoneGap's official documentation for [Upgrading Cordova iOS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html), and followed the section pertaining to updating projects to Cordova 2.0.0, and that helped me get the example working.

Now that I have a working example with Cordova 2.1.0, hopefully I'd be able to replicate that in my project as well.

Comment: is your updated plugin opensourced? can you explain the steps pleasse?